# WinJS AutoSuggestBox get text

Tags: javascript, winjs

I use AutoSuggestBox in my app. I do not how to get text from the input. I want to do search on button click, and I need input text ?

```
<div id="accountsSearchBox" class="searchBox"
    data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AutoSuggestBox"
    data-win-options="{placeholderText: 'Search'}">
</div>
```

I also tried with:

```
data-win-options="{ queryText : value}"
```

and still could not get text with:

```
var queryText = accountsSearchBox.queryText;
```

Do I need this option at all, because I just need get text not set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have solved this. This is correct form:

```
var queryText = accountsSearchBox.winControl.queryText;
```

I forget that "queryText" property is under "winControl".

```
data-win-options="{ queryText : value}"  It is redundant in this case.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **onsuggestionrequested** option.

Read more about this here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301954.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You will then be able to plug it to an event Handler and do what you need to :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just have found solution above. This link is for WinJS.UI.SearchBox, I use WinJS.UI.AutoSuggestBox. I am not sure they have the same features.